# Get Image Uri from from SQLITE Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-permissions

I have a problem with displaying the photo by getting the URI from SQLite.
I picked up an image from gallery using these lines:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

then I received the intent like this in `onActivityResult`:

```
 Intent data = result.getData();
 imageUri = data.getData();
 circleImageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

The image is displayed well in ImageView and there is no problem. But when I stored it in SQLite as String using toString method like this: `imageUri.toString()`.
I got this string from SQLite then parsed it to URI again and tried to display it with imageView put this problem appeared:

```
Permission Denial: opening provider com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider from ProcessRecord{35f7837 4773:com.example.booklibrary/u0a538} (pid=4773, uid=10538) that is not exported from UID 10096
```

what is the problem here, and why I could display the image before storing it and could not display it again after getting it from SQLite!

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: Thank you so much I wasted my time on this problem and finally, now I know the solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

store image URI in sqlite is very bad idea. if the path is delete then your app does not retrieve the image. So if you want to store image in sqlite then convert your image in byte[] and store this byte[] in sqlite in a BLOB column. when you retrieve BOLB then convert byte[] to image and show into image view.

if you don't understand how to store then see this link:

https://abhiandroid.com/database/add-retrieve-image-sqlite-database-example-android-studio.html

Comment: "store image URI in sqlite is very bad idea" -- if you do it correctly, it is not a bad idea. Another reasonable solution is to store a copy of the image in a file that you control and store a filename or something in the database. I do not recommend storing the image in a BLOB column, as Android's wrappers around SQLite do not handle large rows (over 1MB) very well.